# Catching exception multiple times - C#

Tags: c#, exception

```
private void ProcessData(IProcessor processor)
{    
    Data data = new Data();

    try
    {
        processor.Process(data);
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        CustomCode(e);
    }
}
```

Concrete IProcessor `processor.Process` method implementation:

```
public void Process(Data data)
{
    try
    {
        Thing a = null;
        a.MakeSomething();
    }
    catch( NullPointerException e )
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

I would like to run `CustomCode()` method for all Exceptions appearing both in `ProcessData()` method or in its "try" block
(all code in call stack from `ProcessData()` till the end of stack which throws exceptions should be handled by multiple exception handlers - in this example both `DoSomething()` and `CustomCode()` should be run).
How can I achieve this? I know I can add "throw;" after "`DoSomething();`" but this will mean that every programmer in every implementation of the Processor should always remember to write "throw;"
in catch(...) so that `CustomCode(e)` can be run. Can it somehow be done better?

Comment: If you want customerCode to always happen regardless of an exception then there is a design flaw. Why not remove the try catch from the process() and have processdata() handle it. If the exception is handled its handled, you need to choose which should handle what.

Comment: You shouldn´t *catch* a `NullReferenceException` (NPE is java, or do you have your own exception-class), but *avoid* it. Thus there´s no need to even *care* for the exception at all.

Comment: Seabizkit I have another IProcessor implementations. In one of them I commit transaction to database. If exception occurs after commiting this transaction I would like to rollback this transaction.
Each IProcessor implementation should have another exception handling code, depending on what Process(Data data) is doing.

Comment: You can use delegates.If I understand properly ,you want **CustomCode**  and **DoSomething**  to be called whenever an exception occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Seabizkit comment, you might not want to have try-catch in `Process` implementation or at least `throw;` the exception in the end of catch block of `Process` for hiding it is a bad practice.

Otherwise, the solution might be to have a `finally` block in `ProcessData()` where you check if the data was processed (e.g. a special flag was set) and if not, that means that something went wrong and `CustomCode()` has to be executed, but then you don't know what kind of exception that was. Something like:

```
private void ProcessData()
{    
    Data data = new Data();

    try
    {
        Processor processor = new Processor();
        processor.Process(data);
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        CustomCode(e);
    }

    finally {
        if (!data.IsProcessed) CustomCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that solution with finally block is correct :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Process(Data data)
{
  try
  {
    Thing a = null;
    a.MakeSomething();
  }
  catch( NullPointerException e )
  {   
    CustomCode();
    DoSomething();
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
   CustomCode();
 }
```

}

Comment: I want to implement handling exceptions on ProcessData method level, because I have many implementations of Processor classes. I will modify my code that is in question to not confuse you.